# Check if PHP is installed on Apache or IIS Server?

Tags: php, apache, iis

Is there a way to check if PHP is installed on an Apache or IIS server within the PHP environment itself?

If so, how?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

create a file (say info.php) with the following content on an accessible path and try to browse it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

@Alfabravo is correct: don't forget to delete the file from the server after using it!

Comment: ...And then, delete the file from the server after using it.

Comment: Looks like I can also do `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']; ?>`

Answer (score 13):

Create a PHP script called php.php with the content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and run it from your browser. Or from command line, run:

```
php -v
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know with what PHP version it became available, but try this:

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Apache') !== false) 
  echo 'Have Apache';
else
  echo 'Have some other server';
```

Answer (score 6):

The virtually most definitive answer possible (there are other similar possibilities) is:

```php
function on_iis() {
    $sSoftware = strtolower( $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] );
    if ( strpos($sSoftware, "microsoft-iis") !== false )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now, just use `on_iis()` whenever you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find out via the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], sort of:

Read http://www.helicron.net/php/

(Basically, according to the article, Apache sets the document root with a valid variable, and IIS does not).

Comment: Or also `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];`

Comment: IIS sometimes _does_ return a valid DOCUMENT_ROOT - it depends on the server config.