# Cant link css file to Codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add my own CSS file to my Codeigniter/bootstrap project but I have not been able to successfully link the CSS file. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/style.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        jrDash
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
```

When it requests the file this is where the CSS file is being looked for

```
localhost/jrdash/%3C?=base_url()?%3Epublic/css/style.css
```

Comment: Have you auto loaded url helper. Also you could put `<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>"></base>` in the head area. I also have found in the application folder in the htaccess deny all I change it to allow all so can access the css from application

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be with your base_url() function. For one reason or another, your browser is not evaluating the PHP function. This could be for a number of reasons:

1. Apache isn't running on your local environment
2. The file is a .html file instead of a .php file

or other reasons.

You can verify that PHP is running [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486261/check-if-php-is-installed-on-apache-or-iis-server).

Basically, create a new file on your local server, named phpinfo.php, type:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

save, and navigate to that file. If you get a bunch of details about PHP, then it is running. If not, that is your isse.

If it is running, then verify that your above code is in a .php file. There is no reason why what you posted wouldn't be evalutaing as PHP if php is running, and the code is in a .php file.

Once your php function of base_url() works, you should be good to go.

P.S. the best way to use the base_url function in your case would be as follows:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('public/css/style.css')?>">
```