# phar file not running under apache

Tags: php, apache, phar

I am trying to run a simple phar file from a web browser with apache.
I got this from the PHP manual

```
<?php
// creating the phar archive:
try {
    $phar = new Phar('myphar.phar');
    $phar['index.php'] = '<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>';
    $phar['index.phps'] = '<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>';
    $phar->setStub('<?php
Phar::webPhar();
__HALT_COMPILER(); ?>');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle error here
}
?>
```

The manual says

> display Hello World if one browses to /myphar.phar/index.php

However when I do this I get a Not Found

If I navigate to /myphar.phar I still get Not Found but the phar file is downloaded.

How do I set things up so that phar file will work as expected?

Here is how I am attempting to access

```
https://192.168.100.226/myphar.phar/
```

Comment: Do you have PHP running on your Apache install?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Probably not then ;) Take a look at this for checking if it's running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486261/check-if-php-is-installed-on-apache-or-iis-server. Take a look at this if there's no PHP in your Apache install: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-installing-php

Comment: Php is installed - I can access index.php fine just not a phar file

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the following to the httpd.conf

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phar

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! Accept your own answer as correct one.